# How to determine a call made is local or STD OR ISD

Tags: android, android-intent, telephonymanager

I am developing an application which requires to keep track of the outgoing calls made by user, which I am able to track by Using Broadcast Receiver. I also want to detect that is that call is Local or STD or ISD, but I am not able to detect that.

Comment: Looks very interesting, have you been able to figure out the home network of the user for a start? from there u can determine if the call is going out of state or out of country..

Comment: Hi Pinto Could you please explain what exactly "from there u can determine if the call is going out of state or out of country.. " means? As for me "Home network" means getting his current location but how can i proceed with that?

Comment: Home network can help you get the local code that represents it e.g. Mumbai is 022. After that based on number dialed, you can determine ISD. STD might be tricky as mobile phones don't use codes. Landlines might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you know to which *State*(Telecom Circles) the outgoing call is going. Then you just need to check if your *Local-State*(Telecom Circles) is same as *Outgoing-call-State*(Telecom Circles) or not. If it is same, then local call else STD calls.

Now, the problem boils down to, how to find the *State*(Telecom Circles) of an outgoing-calls.

This can be easily done for Landline phones where we specifically put STD codes. See the [link](http://stdcodes.bharatiyamobile.com/) for state and there STD codes.
Interestingly, mobile phones also follow something very similar. First 4 digits of a mobile number tells that. For e.g suppose the number is 9999xxxxxx, then this number is from Delhi - Vodafone. See the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India) for complete mobile phones first 4 digit details.