# How to retrieve STD and Local minutes from calllog in android?

Tags: android, std, local, phone-call, calllog

I am building an android application where I want to retrieve how much user have spend time on Outgoing Local call and Outgoing STD call from phone call log.

I am able to retrieve total time, incoming time and outgoing time from phone call log but I am facing challenge on retrieving information of STD and Local duration.

Below is the code that I am using to retrieve phone number call, date, duration and etc

```
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
```

I search a lot but did not get any think that work.

Comment: I believe your requirement is not feasible unless you have access to mobile network database, refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814031/how-to-determine-a-call-made-to-a-mobile-number-is-local-or-std-or-isd),[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109329/how-to-determine-a-call-made-is-local-or-std-or-isd)

Comment: @SaravInfern how smart app is showing Outgoing STD and Outgoing Local  phone call duration. I don't think so they are doing something as you are explaining me. Can you please suggested me any other way out to fix this.